# Role Based Access Control

Tags: php, codeigniter, access-control

Is there any open-source, `PHP based`, role-based access control system that can be used for `CodeIgniter`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Brandon Savage gave a presentation on his PHP package "[ApplicationACL](http://www.brandonsavage.net/projects.php)" that may or may not accomplish role-based access. [PHPGACL](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/) might work as well, but I can't tell you for sure.

What I can tell you, however, is the [Zend_ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) component of the Zend Framework will do role-based setups (however you'll have to subclass to check multiple roles at once). Granted the pain of this is you'll have to pull out Zend_ACL, I do not believe it has any external dependencies, from the monolithic download (or SVN checkout).

The nice thing about Zend_ACL is though its storage agnostic. You can either rebuild it every time or it's designed to be serialized (I use a combination of both, serialize for the cache and rebuild from the DB).

Comment: Robert: This answer is so old it's best not to follow its advice even if the links still worked

Answer (score 31):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but isn't the whole point of Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) to *avoid* Access Control Lists (ACLs)?

> ***RBAC differs from access control lists (ACLs)** (...) in that it assigns permissions to specific operations with meaning in the organization, rather than to low-level data objects. For example, an access control list could be used to grant or deny write access to a particular system file, but it would not say in what ways that file could be changed. In an RBAC-based system, an operation might be to create a 'credit account' transaction in a financial application (...). The assignment of permission to perform a particular operation is meaningful because the operations are fine-grained and themselves have meaning within the application.*
> (Quote: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control))

I don't know the specifics on Zend_ACL or the other implementations mentioned, but if they are ACL-based, I would not recommend using them for role-based authorization.

Comment: I also have sort of same opinion that wrong answer is accepted for this question .. ACL and RBAC differs much and an ACL solution is accepted for a question on RBAC ..

Comment: Pedantry: "I would not recommend using them for role-based authentication."  access control != authentication    And yes, more importantly ACL != RBAC  ^_^

Comment: @SpainTrain: You're right of course - I've changed it to "role-based authorization"

Answer (score 3):

I created an Open Source project called [PHP-Bouncer](https://github.com/brennydoogles/php-bouncer) which may be of interest to you. It's still fairly young, but works well and is easy to configure. I ended up developing it because none of the existing solutions seemed to meet my needs. I hope this helps!

Comment: what needs did you have that your project meets? Otherwise this is just an ad.

Comment: Since the OP was asking for an "open source, PHP based, role based access control system", and PHP-Bouncer is an open source, PHP based, role based access control system, I figured it would be pretty fitting.

Comment: PHP-Bouncer was moved to Github a while back, I've updated the link. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 1):

phpgacl http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/ is a generic acl based access control framework

while I don't know about any CI specific implementation, i know that you only need the main class file to make phpgacl work. So i belive that integration with CI won't be any problem. (I've work passingly with CI)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two RBAC libraries for PHP I found:

- https://github.com/leighmacdonald/php_rbac
- https://github.com/brandonlamb/php-rbac

I actually used the first one in PolyAuth: https://github.com/Polycademy/PolyAuth/

It's a full featured auth library that includes NIST level 1 RBAC. And yes, RBAC is not the same as an ACL. I use Codeigniter as well, all you have to do is use the PDO driver and pass in the connection id. See this tutorial for how to do that: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/03/codeigniter-with-pdo

Answer (score 0):

Found out about Khaos ACL which is a CI library... I'm also checking out phpgacl and how to use it for CI... Have'nt checked Zend ACL yet. But maybe it can be "ported" to CI

Answer (score 0):

Try DX_Auth plugin for CodeIgniter. I am working on a similar (rather, superset) of the functions that DX_Auth have. My set of CI addon's include display of menus (that can be controlled via CSS), Role-bases access controll before controller is invoked and other features. I hope to publish it soon. Will give project URL when  I do so

Answer (score 0):

RBAC != ACL - Roland has the only correct answer for this question.

BTW of course it is an essential part of a framework to implement any kind of permission system - at least there is no point in using a framework, if it does not give you a well engeneered RBAC system - it might be better using a simple template system with any ORM layer then.

It is a common antipattern in the php world, that frameworks like Ruby or Django are "cloned" only as a subset of what these modern frameworks deliver - as a typical syndrome yuo see a lack of good ACL or RBAC integration into these frameworks - what essentially is a joke. 
There is currently only the Yii PHP Framework that comes with a decent RBAC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

<s>http://www.jframework.info</s> (deadlink)

jFramework has a standard NIST level 2 RBAC with enhancements which is said to be the fastest available (includes benchmarks) it can operate on a single SQLite database file and is tested thoroughly, works like a glove.

Has a dependency on jFramework DBAL but you can simple replace DBAL SQL Queries in the code with your desired DBAL and of course you can use jFramework in a SOP manner.

Answer (score 0):

I know the trail is cold, but a new project has popped up :

PHP-RBAC is a PHP Hierarchical NIST Level 2 Standard Role Based Access Control and is pretty mature. It is also an OWASP project.

I hope you enjoy it at http://phprbac.net

Comment: You posted the exact same answer in other questions.. Are you the developer?

Comment: I am one of the developers.

Answer (score -1):

Ion Auth Library uses users and groups - https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth
but there are no working RBAC system to use them and manage. But you can white your functions.