# Blogging with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, blogs

I've been following a tutorial to make a blog in PHP and MySQL. But at the end of the tutorial, the finished blog lets any user who comes to the website edit the categories and post. What would be the best way to limit certain portions of the website to myself? I've thought of a login system where only I can login, or there might be a way in .htaccess. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PHP [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

You'll need some list of users to authenticate against. If this is a database, create a Users table, with columns username and password.

At the beginning of every page you put `start_session()`. This retains the session between pages.

Create a login page and link. On the login page, you authenticate the passed in username and hashed password against your list of users. If the user passes authentication, you add a session variable that stores which user is logged in. Also, [regenerate the session ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) after login to prevent session hijacking.

On every page that requires member access, you check to ensure the user is logged in. If not, you redirect them to the login page.

If you use .htaccess to setup HTTP basic authentication, you'll want to block just the pages that allow the user to edit the blog.

Consider adding SSL (HTTPS) in either case, otherwise, login credentials can be stolen if people are on an open network.

Answer (score 1):

Build your own ACL layer, check the web for resources but this link should be a good starting point

[Implement ACL in PHP - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415663/implementing-acl-for-my-php-application)

Answer (score 0):

Both ways you mention can work.

Or you can just install a robust, secure, feature full blog. For example http://wordpress.org

Answer (score 0):

Make a user login module and use session check for that place for example user logged in and his you store his user id or something in `$_SESSION['is_user']` then check for private content

```
if(isset($_SESSION['is_user'])){
//Show
} else {
//Redirect to login page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first alter the links to post editing page and use a login system .

sample code,

save file as : **login.php**

```
<form method="post">
name : <input name="name">
password : <input name="name">
<button> login </button>
</form>
<?php 
session_start();
define('name','your name');
define('password','your password');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "post"){
if($_POST['name' == name && $_POST['password'] == password){
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'yes';
header('location:admin.php'); //you can change this
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a personal blog or similar thing, it's better use one that is supported by the community, you don't need reinvent the whell, use your time for something more productive.

The choices that you have are:

- Wordpress, he has a big community and great documentation. http://wordpress.com/
- Habari, the big thing of habari is that is designed using OOP. http://habariproject.org/en/

Comment: That's not the solution of problem :p

Comment: DRY, if someone did this before, you can save time do other things.

The problem in self is the question, why he needs to do this...? but ok, if he need to do access control list, Zen have a good library, the Zen_ACL.