# How can I secure or authenticate access to XML files?

Tags: xml, security, authentication

I have a XML file that saves email template information, and one thing contained therein is user emails. Is there a way to ensure that only logged in users can access this file? For instance, I would like to do something like this for a PHP page:

```
require("checklogin.php")
```

Comment: What platform are you using? PHP?

Comment: Apologies, I thought this was an ASP.Net question. I had answered with that assumption. What platform?

Comment: I don't see how the file being an XML file has anything to do with the question. You're just trying to implement some kind of identity and access control system at all at this point, right? (Also, I gave your question a copyedit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing ACL for my PHP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415663/implementing-acl-for-my-php-application)