# Returning the results only when the user has permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am wondering if there are any better ways to deal with this scenario. Although, its simple, keeping number of hits in mind, I am trying to eliminate a query.

I have list of `Books`. Only users assigned to this book can see books and other contents in it. Its basically API call. `/Books/`, `/Books/Chapters/`, `/Books/Chapters/Pages/`, etc. The permissions are attached to `Books` entry in the database.

`Books`, 'Chapters`,`Pages`, etc are all in different tables.
User permissions are stored in a different table. The table is something like this.

```
    UserID,  BookID
    --------------
     101      1
     102      1
     102      2
     ...
```

User info is grabbed from  the API call itself (Basic Auth).
The API should return `401 Unauthorized`, if the requested `Book` exist, but the user does not have permissions to that `Book`. If the requested 'Book`does not exist, then it should return`404 Not found`.

Usually, first I need to check the permission for that user and for the requested `Book`, with a query. If the record exists in the user permission table for that user, then I should run the another query to get the `Book`, 'Chapter`, etc.

Currently, I am combing these two queries with 'WHERE EXISTS`condition that checks for the existence of the record for this user for the requested`Book` in the permissions table. So the records will be returned only when there is a record in the user permission table.

But with this, I will not know, if the `Book` does not exist or if the user does not have permission, though I could cut down one database call to check user permission separately. And with this, I cannot distinguish `401` and `404`.

Is there a better way to do this while being able to distinguish `401` and `404` with a singe query?
Or its better to do two database calls?

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you embed a subquery like this.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT
         1
     FROM
         permissions
     WHERE
         permissions.user_id=<user ID> AND permissions.book_id=<book ID>)
    ) AS Permission,
    *
FROM
    books
WHERE
    books.id=<book ID>
```

You'll have a new column named "Permission" which will be 1 if the user has permission or NULL if the user doesn't have permission to the book.

**EDIT:** I simplified the subquery by having it return either "1" or "NULL".

Comment: So your query returns results along with User Permissions? I guess it returns the results, if exists, even when user does not have permissions. But instead of 1, it just returns null?

Comment: @Kevin: that's correct. The results for the book (if it exists) are always returned. The determination of user access is based on the value of the new Permission column (1 or NULL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your applicatin ACLs (Access Control Lists) That way you can assign permissions to various entities in your database. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415663/implementing-acl-for-my-php-application)