# how to make user access level using pdo?

Tags: php, pdo

i have here the code for login and it works fine i also use session here but my problem now is that how can i suppose to make a user access level?.in my login database i have username, password and level, now admin=1 and guest=0.
what i want to happen is that when i login as admin it will redirect me to signup.php and if i login as guest it will redirect me to index.php, please help me i'm working this for almost two weeks..
here is my code..

**db.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";
$DB_name = "survey";
$charset = "utf8";


try
{
  $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name};charset={$charset}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
  $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
  catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**class.user.login.php**

```
<?php

class crud
{
private $db;

function __construct($DB_con)
{
  $this->db = $DB_con;
}

public function login($uname,$upass)
{
try
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname AND level=:level LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
  $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
    {
      $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}

public function is_loggedin()
{
if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
{
    return true;
  }
}

public function redirect($url)
{
header("Location: $url");
}
?>
```

****login.php****

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if($crud->is_loggedin()!="")
    {
    $crud->redirect('insert.php');
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    $uname = $_POST['user'];
    $upass = $_POST['pass'];

    if($crud->login($uname,$upass))
    {
    $crud->redirect('index.php');
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Username or Password');</script>";
    }   
}
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(!$crud->is_loggedin())
    {
    $crud->redirect('home.php');
    }
    $ID = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM survey_section WHERE ID=:ID");
    $stmt->execute(array(":ID"=>$ID));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is ACL (Access Control List)

<sup>*[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415733/2518525) should help you gain an understanding :-)*</sup>

---

For your current implementation, there is no checking what `level` the logged in user is, you only seem to `$crud->redirect('index.php');` if the login is successful.

But before we get to that section; you're trying to bind `:level` yet not specifying it or implementing it anywhere...

In your `login()` method you have:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname AND level=:level LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
```

That is going to fail as you haven't specified what `:level` is, hence you'll be thrown an invalid parameter count error -> meaning this function will always return false.

You need to modify that query (*either removing `AND level = :level`* ***or*** *specifying what `:level` is in your `execute()`.*)

From there, you'll need to modify your functions appropriately - in this case, setting level into a session variable would be more fitting:

```
//.....code above...
if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
{
  $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
  $_SESSION['user_level'] = $userRow['level'];
  return true;
}
//.....cove below...
```

Now; from within your `login.php`, you can redirect accordingly:

```
if($crud->login($uname,$upass))
{
    switch($_SESSION['user_level']) {
        case "0": // regular user
        $crud->redirect('index.php');
        break;
        case "1": // admin
        $crud->redirect('signup.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about in home.php do i need to change anything in the session?

Comment: @Trojan Depends what you want to do in `home.php`. Who can access it?

Comment: yeah i know that..like for example in your code when i login as guest i will be redirected in index.php, do i need to put anything in my home.php like my code above?

Comment: @Trojan that depends - do you want the same redirect to happen based on the user level?

Comment: yeah..so if that the case i dont need to change anything right?

Comment: If that's the case, then you just need to copy the `switch/case` code there :-) to redirect accordingly.

Comment: do i need to change my if statement?