# How to separate privileges for admin and registered user ?

Tags: php, admin, privileges

My website basically have two main users; admin and registered user. How can I make different privileges between these two users ? What is the easiest way to control the privileges of the users ? Do I have to make if-else statement at the top of the every page ? Or do I need to create a new php file and put include (file.php) in every page ? I need some idea and some example of coding because I am totally lost and don't know where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: check out role based access control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113543/role-based-access-control

Answer (score 0):

Create a column in users called admin, tinyint(1)
Create a function that checks for auth, so for example:

```
function needAdmin() {

// query db(or lookup $_SESSIONS or something) and check if the guy is admin,
$row = $result->fetch_object();
if(!$row->admin) exit();
}
```

exit can be replaced by anything you like to do!

make a file that includes the page instead of a page that includes all includes. 
that way you only have to edit it on one page and can use the function everywhere